# Sum over primes of $\log \log p$

Tags: number-theory

Are there good upper and lower estimates of 
$$
A(x):=\sum_{p \leq x} \log \log p
$$
ignoring the first negative term?

Magma says

> sum until 100 is  28.55
>
> sum until  1000  is  286.41
>
> sum until  10000  is  2544.87
>
> sum until  100000  is  22382.24
>
> sum until  1000000  is  199280.38
>
> sum until  10000000  is  1799506.07

and the growth seems faster than a fixed power of log x.

Answer (score 2):

Using $p_n\sim n\log n$,

$$A(n\log n)\sim\sum_{k=3}^n\log\log(k\log k)\sim\sum_{k=3}^n\log\log k.$$

Then from

$$\int\log\log x\,dx=x\log\log x-\text{Li}(x)$$

and

$$\text{Li(x)}\sim\frac x{\log x}$$ making this term negligible, we draw

$$\sum_{k=3}^n\log\log k\sim n\log\log n.$$

Now, with $n\log n=m$,

$$m\sim\frac n{\log n}$$ and finally

$$A(m)\sim\frac m{\log m}\log\log\frac m{\log m}\sim\frac{m\log\log m}{\log m}.$$

Due to the fact that the summand is growing extremely slowly, I guess that empirical observation of the asymptotic behavior is hopeless, though the agreement to the given data looks fair.

[image]